# Clustering multivalue nominal attributes with different measures

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I have to apply a clustering algorithm to my dataset which is composed by elements composed by attributes of different nature:

```
A1 -> multivalued, nominal values
A2 -> multivalued, nominal values
A3 -> multivalued, nominal values
A4 -> single nominal value
```

The domain of each attribute is potentially huge, such as a dictionary word.

I've just found Jaccard measure, wich will be great for each attribute values-set, except for the first one.

Consider the following example

```
E1: [ 
    A1 (ab,bb), 
    A2 (Mark, Rose, Bet), 
    A3 (rock, pop, soul),
    A4 (France)
    ],

E2: [ 
    A1 (ab,bb,cc,ca), 
    A2 (Mark, Peter, Bet, Louise), 
    A3 (pop, disco),
    A4 (Spain),
    ]
```

While all the other attributes must be considerend as made of atomic value, the first attribute is composed by values that needs to be compared with string similarity, such as Levenshtein distance.

Which is the best approach? The first attribute is generally of small cardinality, about 10 values. But I have no a priori knowledge. All the other attributes have a huge cardinality.

I'm new to clustering stuff, I'm just trying to figure out how to do it in the best way :)

I have found that R software should be a good way to implement that kind of clustering (consider a dataset of milions of elements).

Any suggestion?